Recover mysql database from /var/lib/mysql-previous/
I've had wordpress site running in a linux server.
Then I installed cyberpanel, that moved the previously installed instance of mysql database to folder under "/var/lib/mysql-previous"
Now I want to recover my previous wordpress website (I've all the wordpress files) and I can also find my previous mysql instance with wordpress database, but I'm unable to recover it.
Can anyone please tell me How can I move my database/tables from mysql-previous to my current mysql?
I tried the command
mysqld --datadir=/var/lib/mysql-previous --user=mysql &
but it also gave me error:
2024-04-04 17:03:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-04-04 17:03:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2024-04-04 17:03:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2024-04-04 17:03:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.       000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2024-04-04 17:03:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-04-04 17:03:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: File ./ib_logfile0 was not found
2024-04-04 17:03:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error G       eneric error
2024-04-04 17:03:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2024-04-04 17:03:06 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE f       ailed.
2024-04-04 17:03:06 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-04-04 17:03:06 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.p       lugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
2024-04-04 17:03:06 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2024-04-04 17:03:06 0 [ERROR] Aborting

[3]   Exit 1                  mysqld --datadir=/var/lib/mysql-previous --user=my       sql

As it says File ./ib_logfile0 was not found
I also tried for recovery:
root@IUMS-OIC:/# sudo mysqld --datadir=/var/lib/mysql-previous --innodb_force_recovery=1 --user=mysql

but is says:
2024-04-04 17:31:35 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.11.7-MariaDB-1:10.11.7+maria~ubu2204 source revision 87e13722a95af5d9378d990caf48cb6874439347 as process 72435
2024-04-04 17:31:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 1 !!!
2024-04-04 17:31:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-04-04 17:31:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2024-04-04 17:31:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2024-04-04 17:31:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2024-04-04 17:31:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-04-04 17:31:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: File ./ib_logfile0 was not found
2024-04-04 17:31:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2024-04-04 17:31:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2024-04-04 17:31:36 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2024-04-04 17:31:36 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-04-04 17:31:36 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
2024-04-04 17:31:36 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2024-04-04 17:31:36 0 [ERROR] Aborting
root@IUMS-OIC:/#

For reference, here's my directory list
root@IUMS-OIC:/# ls /var/lib/mysql-previous/

 aria_log.00000001   ca-key.pem          '#innodb_redo'        server-key.pem
 aria_log_control    ca.pem              '#innodb_temp'        sys
 auto.cnf            client-cert.pem      mysql                undo_001
 binlog.000003       client-key.pem       mysql.ibd            undo_002
 binlog.000004      '#ib_16384_0.dblwr'   performance_schema   wordpress
 binlog.000005      '#ib_16384_1.dblwr'   private_key.pem
 binlog.000006       ib_buffer_pool       public_key.pem
 binlog.index        ibdata1              server-cert.pem
root@IUMS-OIC:/#

Can anyone please guide me?

It looks like the previous directory is MySQL rather than MariaDB. Try running MySQL on mysql-previous, and then try to get a SQL dump form that instance - like podman run -v /var/lib/mysql-previous:/var/lib/mysql --name m80 mysql:8.0 and the podman exec m80 mysqldump wordpress > /tmp/wp.sql; and then import wp.sql.
